# Direct credi card payment api for Brazil?

Tags: android, api, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I need a direct credi card payment api for my Android App, I have used paypal, but paypal not support "BRL" ([Brazil currency](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/#creditcard)) for direct credi card payment.

Anyone know any API that solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brazilian real(BRL) is only supported for PayPal Payments and it is only supported for in country paypal accounts. You can see the official document [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/).